# In statement not accepting Select?

Tags: sql

If I have:

```
select * from Dealer DDDD
left join Filter FFFF on DDDD.dealer_id = FFFF.DealerId
WHERE FFFF.FilterId IN (CASE WHEN EXISTS (Select 1 from @filterIds) THEN (Select FilterId from @filterIds) ELSE FFFF.FilterId END)
```

`@filterIds` is a table value parameter which im testing having 2 records.
if I have it as null or only 1 value there is no problem but if 2 or more im getting "Subquery returned more than 1 value when the subquery is used as an expression." error.

I tried to test it just having:

```
WHERE FFFF.FilterId IN (Select FilterId from @filterIds)
```

and it works.

but what I need it to have it with the consideration that a filter might not be inputed.

THanks in advance guys!

Comment: `where  FFFF.FilterId =  FFFF.FilterId`  is always true execpt when is NULL. It is not clear what you ask. Also, error is clear, you can't return more than 1 value in case statemen. Add data sample an expected results

Comment: I want to return everything if @filterIds have 0 row

Comment: I also tried:

AND FFF.FilterId IN (COALESCE((Select FilterId from @filterIds), FFFF.FilterId))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case` is an expression that returns a value.  In most databases, a comparison is not a scalar expression.  Try:

```
select *
from Dealer DDDD left join
     Filter FFFF
     on DDDD.dealer_id = FFFF.DealerId
where not exists (Select 1 from @filterIds) or
      FFFF.FilterId in (Select FilterId from @filterIds);
```